# Generalized Union and Intersection Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone help me with this question? I would greatly appreciate it!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$A_{i-1} \subseteq A_{i}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $A_1 = \{1\}, A_2 = \{1,2\}, A_3 = \{1,2,3\}$ etc. Now, what set do you get when you take all the elements that are in any of these sets, and what set do you get when you take all the elements that all the sets have in common?